# Swipe gesture in iPhone SDK 4.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk, swipe

How do i put a swipe gesture in the new iPhone SDK?  I'm trying to detect a swipe gesture over a UIImageView?  A swipe up and a swipe down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to override onTouchesBegan and onTouchesEnded. When it begins, record the first position, then at the end compare the last touch to the first touch to see if it is lower or higher.

Comment: This really is _not_ the way to do it. Since he's using iOS4 he can use the new `UIGestureRecognizer` which were made for this purpose. Ohmu's answer is better suited.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new API for this:  Refer to this post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809397/ios-advanced-gestures-getting-swipe-direction-vector/).

Answer (score 4):

There are easier ways to handle gestures in iOS 4.0 see:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Answer (score 2):

please download the swipe gesture code from this link:

https://github.com/brow/leaves/downloads

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *settingbtnpress =
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(MethodName)];
settingbtnpress.delegate=self;
settingbtnpress.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:settingbtnpress];
[settingbtnpress release];
```