# UIScrollView Horizontal scrolling - Disable left scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I disable scrolling left on a UIScrollview. This is so users can only scroll right?

Thanks

***** UPDATE ***********

This is what I have now. I have subclassed UIScrollView and overwritten the following methods

```
@implementation TouchScrollView

- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view {
    NSLog(@"touchesShouldBegin: I was touched!");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    NSLog(@"touchesShouldCancelInContentView: I was touched!");
    return NO;
}
```

In my viewController I have also set the following attributes:

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

TouchesShouldBegin is being called but touchesShouldCancelInContentView is not being called and I cant figure out why!!

Thanks

Comment: i have the same issue.did u find out why canCancelContentTouches never gets called even id canCancelContentTouches is set to YES?

Answer (score 1):

just add this in your UIViewController UIScrollViewDelegate

```
float oldX; // here or better in .h interface

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < oldX) {
        [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(oldX, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    } else {
        oldX = aScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    }

}
```

Comment: not working on the Ipad. If you scroll quickly it will scroll on the left direction then after do [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(oldX, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];

Answer (score 0):

You should handle swipe gestures.

Check similar question here: [iOS Advanced Gestures: Getting Swipe Direction Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809397/ios-advanced-gestures-getting-swipe-direction-vector)

Comment: Unless of course he wants to support older iOS versions, in which case he shouldn't.