# Disable right scrolling in uiscrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, image

How can i disable left or right scrolling in scrollview in iPhone?

can any one give the code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041160/uiscrollview-horizontal-scrolling-disable-left-scroll

Answer (score 1):

```
 CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(320, myScrollableHeight);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

You have to set the contentSize property of the UIScrollView. Like, if your UIScrollView is 320 pixels wide (the width of the screen), then you could do this

The UIScrollView will then only scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

set your scrolview width 320. It will

like

```
[self.scrolview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrolview.frame.origin.x,self.scrolview.frame.origin.y,320,self.scrolview.frame.size.height)];
```